# Adding a QgsLayoutItemMapGrid to a QgsLayoutItemMap with PyQGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis-3, qgis-print-layouts

I'm trying to add a grid to a map but I don't get any results. My code:

```py
def add_map_layout_item(self,
                        list_maplayers,
                        qgs_rectangle,
                        origin_x_mm,
                        origin_y_mm,
                        width_mm,
                        height_mm,
                        grid_interval): 

    map = QgsLayoutItemMap(self.layout)
    map.updateBoundingRect()
    map.setRect(QRectF(origin_x_mm, origin_y_mm, width_mm, height_mm))
    map.setPos(origin_x_mm, origin_y_mm)
    map.setFrameEnabled(True)

    map.setLayers(list_maplayers)       
    map.setKeepLayerSet(True)
    map.setExtent(qgs_rectangle)
    self.iface.mapCanvas().freeze(True)

    map.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(origin_x_mm, origin_y_mm))
    map.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(width_mm, height_mm))
    map.zoomToExtent(qgs_rectangle)

    qgs_layout_item_map_grid = QgsLayoutItemMapGrid("New grid",
                                                        map)
    qgs_layout_item_map_grid.setAnnotationPrecision(0)  
    qgs_layout_item_map_grid.setAnnotationFrameDistance(1) 
    qgs_layout_item_map_grid.setAnnotationFontColor(QColor(0, 0, 0)) 
    qgs_layout_item_map_grid.setCrossLength(1.0)  
    qgs_layout_item_map_grid.setIntervalX(grid_interval)  
    qgs_layout_item_map_grid.setIntervalY(grid_interval)  

    self.layout.addLayoutItem(map)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? I am trying to find the solution to this problem myself.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in this [link](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Developer-How-do-I-add-a-QgsLayoutItemMapGrid-to-a-QgsLayoutItemMap-with-PyQGIS-3-x-td5404845.html):

```
map.grids().addGrid(qgs_layout_item_map_grid)
```

Another option would be the following:

```py
self.layout.addLayoutItem(map)    
map.grid().setEnabled(True)  
map.grid().setIntervalX(grid_interval)  
map.grid().setIntervalY(grid_interval)  
map.grid().setAnnotationEnabled(True) 
map.grid().setGridLineColor(QColor(0, 176, 246))  
map.grid().setGridLineWidth(0.5)
map.grid().setAnnotationPrecision(0)  
map.grid().setAnnotationFrameDistance(1)  
map.grid().setAnnotationFontColor(QColor(0, 0, 0)) 
map.grid().setAnnotationDisplay(QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.HideAll, QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.Right)
map.grid().setAnnotationDisplay(QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.HideAll, QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.Top)
map.grid().setAnnotationPosition(QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.OutsideMapFrame, QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.Bottom)
map.grid().setAnnotationDirection(QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.Horizontal, QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.Bottom)
map.grid().setAnnotationPosition(QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.OutsideMapFrame, QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.Left)
map.grid().setAnnotationDirection(QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.Vertical, QgsLayoutItemMapGrid.Left)

(...) 

map.updateBoundingRect()
```